# getting data from address bar to make mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, networking

qIn rest API this short of URL appears:

```
http://api.example.com/v1/curated-content?location=india&contenttype=image&category=celeb&orderby=popularity&apikey=15svzH8qSy5yQuF52b068a40a69e
```

in my database I have content like location, category, apikey,contenttype etc.

How can I fetch these data when user makes request like in aboce URL?

Comment: look into how GET works

Comment: you have to read php documentation, you have learn a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking how to access Parameters that were sent via GET-Method.
All these Parameters can be accessed via the associative $_GET-Array in PHP.

So if location=india and you do

```
echo $_GET['location'];
```

that would output

```
india
```

When creating SQL-Queries from these variables keep in mind that the user could manipulate the URL and insert harmful values in your code (so called SQL-Injection). Always mask such data with the mysql_real_escape_string function in PHP.